# Android: VLC-android-sdk increase 60MB to my apk file size

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, libvlc

My apk file size is 5MB

After adding the `"de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:2.0.6"` to gradle, apk size increase to 62MB.

How can I resolve it?

Note: I changed it to this, But it didn't work.

```
compile ("de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:2.0.6"){
   exclude group: 'io.card'
}
```

Comment: VLC is big, what did you expect? I'm actually asking how big increase were you expecting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VLC uses *lots* of native code. As a result, it has 18-30MB of native libraries per CPU architecture. While that will be compressed somewhat in the APK, a 57MB increase in APK is actually better than I would expect.

You either need to:

- Live with it, or
- Use splits or product flavors to indicate which subset of CPU architectures you are willing to support (the library itself supports `arm64-v8a`, `armeabi-v7a`, `mips`, `x86`, and `x86_64`), or
- Do not use VLC

Comment: Instead VLC, use from what ?

Comment: @AliRez: I have no idea. Many developers just use the native media playback APIs (e.g., `MediaPlayer`, `SoundPool`).

Comment: I haven't tried https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer but it may be smaller.

Comment: yes my application size also increases from 9mb to 43mb when i add vlc android sdk in my application. but its the best player according to me.