# SQLCipher and CWAC-SafeRoom doubling the size of my APK

Tags: android-room, sqlcipher, commonsware-cwac, sqlcipher-android

The size of these libraries really increase the APK size. It’s almost **50%** my App size, taking it to **16.3 MBs** and when I analyze the APK, sqlcipher-lib alone is **48.9%** of my apk size i.e **7.3MBs!!!**

Is there any workaround?

[image]

**Edit:**
Since this is a DB related issue and I believe it's good if the specified tags remain referenced for specificity during search by other developers.
 I think the answer below addresses it better in order to keep the conversation along specific topics

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: vlc-android-sdk increase 60MB to my apk file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45121130/android-vlc-android-sdk-increase-60mb-to-my-apk-file-size)

Answer (score 0):

[This section of the thread](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-for-android-room-and-api-level-16/2161/35?u=champisme) that has seen the realization of [SafeRoom](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-saferoom) better explains the solution. Which is precisely; **Stay with the problem** in order to support different architectures. So I had to continue with this proguard rule;

```
-keep class net.sqlcipher.** {
    *;
}
```

which keeps the sizable classes.